# How to calculate the cardinality of following set

Tags: group-theory, summation, finite-fields, cardinals, primitive-roots

If $$A = \bigg\{\sum_{i=0}^4a_i x^{i}+b_i x^{i}y \ \big| \bigg(\sum_{i=0}^4a_iw^i\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{i=0}^4a_iw^{4i}\bigg) = 0: a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{F}_{2^k}\bigg\}$$ where $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}$ is a field with $2^k$ elements for some positive integer $k$ and $w$ is primitive $5^{th}$ root of unity, $x, y$ are generators of dihederal group of order $10$.

I want to prove that cardinality of $A$ is $2^{4k+1}-2^{3k}$. How to think?

Comment: Does your condition involve $b_i$ as well? So maybe $\sum_i b_i w^{4i}$ is the second factor?

Comment: No this is not involved in the product

Comment: So i think $2^{5k}$ are the possibilities for $b_i$'s as these are arbitrary.

Comment: OK, then expand that product in the condition, using $w^4=w^{-1}$ and that should help.

Comment: I am getting $5$ equations. Don't know how to proceed further,

Comment: @ see the edits.

Comment: So $A$ is a subset of the group algebra $\Bbb{F}_{2^k}[D_5]$? If so,  why keep that a secret? Anyway, we are still free to choose the $b_i$s any which way we want, and those elements of the group algebra are linearly independent over $\Bbb{F}_{2^k}$. So the answer is $2^{5k}$ times the number of choices for the vector $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$. The constraint equation is satisfied if and only if the polynomial $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4$ has either $w$ or $w^{-1}$ as its zero. The formula depends on the residue class of $k$ modulo $4$. This is because $w\in\Bbb{F}_{2^4}$.

Comment: (cont'd) So if $K=\Bbb{F}_{2^k}$ then $w$ is an element of $K$, iff $4\mid k$. $[K(w):K]=2$, if $k\equiv2\pmod 4$, and $[K(w):K]=4$, if $k$ is odd. The minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $w$ is in the respective cases thus $x+w$, $x^2+\omega x+1$ with $\omega$ a third root of unity, and $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. In the latter two cases $w$ and $w^{-1}$ share a minimial polynomial, so in those cases the second factor of the constraint is superfluous.

Comment: Looks like this is a variant of either [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2678831/11619), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2679046/11619), or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2679126/11619). I'm not sure what's going on, but this is not good for site hygiene. Mittal, care to explain what are you trying to achieve here?