# How to find no. of polynomials over a finite field satisfying given condition.

Tags: polynomials, roots, finite-fields, roots-of-unity

If i am given with a polynomial $$g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^4 a_ix^i$$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{F}_{2^k}$, finite field with $2^k$ elements. How to find out the no of such polynomials $g(x)$ such that either $g(w) = 0$ or $g(w^{-1}) = 0$, where $w$ is primitive $5^{th}$ root of unity.

Comment: What is a primitive fifth root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{2^k}?$

Comment: I am assuming $5/ {2^k-1}$

Comment: This is probably an evolved version of [this earlier question by the same asker](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2678831/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the number of polynomials $g(x)$ of degree $\le4$ such that $g(x)$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial of either $w$ or $w^{-1}$ over $K=\Bbb{F}_{2^k}$. The answer depends on the degree of those minimal polynomials (they actually coincide for three quarters of choices of $k$), so we split the treatment accordingly.

A key parameter is the extension degree $m=[K(w):K]$. Because $5\mid (2^4-1)$, the smallest field containing $w$ is $\Bbb{F}_{2^4}$. Therefore the extension degree $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $4\mid (mk)$. An alternative way of saying the same thing is that $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $5\mid 2^{mk}-1$. Clearly, $m=4$ when $k$ is odd, $m=2$ when $k\equiv2\pmod4$ and $m=1$ when $4\mid k$.

**Case 1**: $m=1$, or $4\mid k$. In this case $5\mid 2^k-1$ so $w$ is actually an element of $K$ as is obviously also $w^{-1}=w^4$. The minimal polynomial of $w$ is $x-w$. Therefore we have $g(w)=0$ if and only if $g(x)=(x-w)h(x)$ for some polynomial $h(x)=h_0+h_1x+h_2x^2+h_3x^3\in K[x]$. All those four coefficients $h_i$ can be chosen freely, so there are $2^{4k}$ such polynomials. Similarly we see that $g(w^{-1})=0$ if and only if $g(x)=(x-w^{-1})h(x)$ for some at most cubic polynomial $h(x)$. Superficially this gives us another $2^{4k}$ polynomials $g(x)$. But, we are double counting those polynomials $g(x)$ that have both $w$ and $w^{-1}$ as zeros. This happens if and only if 
$g(x)=(x-w)(x-w^{-1})f(x)$ for some polynomial $f(x)$ that can be at most quadratic. As $f(x)=f_0+f_1x+f_2x^2$ has three coefficients we can choose freely, there are $2^{3k}$ ways this can happen. The conclusion is that

> when $4\mid k$ the number of polynomials $g(x)$ is $2^{4k}+2^{4k}-2^{3k}=2^{4k+1}-2^{3k}$.

**Case 2**: $m=2$, or $k\equiv2\pmod4$. Here $5\nmid 2^k-1$ but $5\mid 2^{2k-1}=(2^k-1)(2^k+1)$. Therefore $5\mid 2^k+1$ and $2^k\equiv-1\pmod5$. In this case the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $w$ over $K$ is a quadratic. By Galois theory
$$m(x)=(x-w)(x-w^{2^k})=(x-w)(x-w^{-1})=x^2+\omega x+1,$$
where $\omega=w+w^{-1}$ is an element of $K$. Actually, aided by [a discrete logarithm table of $\Bbb{F}_{16}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) we can easily verify that $\omega$ is one of the third primitive roots of unity in $K$ (the choice of the third root of unity depends on the choice of which fifth root of unity we call $w$). Anyway, in this case $g(w)=0$ if and only if $g(w^{-1})=0$ if and only if $g(x)=m(x)f(x)$ for some polynomial $f(x)=f_0+f_1x+f_2x^2$. Again, we can choose the coefficients $f_0,f_1,f_2$ any which way we want and

> when $k\equiv2\pmod4$ the number of such polynomials $g(x)$ is $2^{3k}$.

**Case 3**: $m=4$, $k$ odd. In this time the minimal polynomial of $w$ has degree four. Because $w$ is trivially a zero of $m(x)=(x^5-1)/(x-1)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, this is then also the minimal polynomial. As in case 2, $m(x)$ is also the minimal polynomial of $w^{-1}$. In this case we must have
$g(x)=m(x)r(x)$, but by considering the degrees we see that $r(x)$ must be a constant polynomial. Therefore there are $2^k$ choices of $r(x)$.

> When $k$ is odd the number of polynomials $g(x)$ with either $w$ or $w^{-1}$ as a zero is $2^k$.

Comment: Thanks. Beautifully explained.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is: $1.$ Indeed, $q(x) = \sum_{i=0}^4 x^i$ is such a polynomial (for both $w$ and $1/w$), now let $g(x)$ be your polynomial, and consider $h(x)=g(x) - a_0 q(x)$ this will vanish at $w,$ but it is divisible by $x,$ and if $h(x)$ were not the zero polynomial, $w$ would satisfy an equation of degree less than four, which would make it not primitive.

Comment: No i think answer is greater than $2^{k}$ as take all $a_i's $ equal, possible choices are then $2^k$

Comment: But i am looking for or not and. means anyone can be a root.

Comment: @MittalG Say what?

Comment: Apparently the OP is not constrained to monic polynomials so you get more. Also observe that we are not constrained to polynomials with coefficients in the prime field. The question is admittedly not very clear.